# Autofac inject properties on ApiController in combination with RegisterApiControllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, autofac, autofac-configuration

I want to inject `Modules` and `Data` properties from an `autofac.json` file into my `ApiController` with name `DataController`

I read this page:
http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/configuration/xml.html but my properties keep being `NULL`, so I must be doing wrong something. Who can help me?

My `Controller` already has an contructor where an instance of `ILog` is being injected, so these properties are extra.

This is the `Autofac` configuration I have now:

```cs
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterApiControllers(typeof(Startup).Assembly); // to register all ApiControllers at once

// Use the Microsoft Configuration Extensions together with Autofac to create an Autofac Module
var autofacConfig = new ConfigurationBuilder();
autofacConfig.AddJsonFile("autofac.json");
var autofacModule = new  ConfigurationModule(autofacConfig.Build());
builder.RegisterModule(autofacModule);

var container = builder.Build();

var httpConfigurationConfig = new HttpConfiguration { DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container) };

app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
app.UseAutofacWebApi(httpConfigurationConfig );
app.UseWebApi(httpConfigurationConfig );
```

This is my `autofac.json`:

```json
{
  "components": [
    {
      "type": "Web.Controllers.DataController, Web",
      "injectProperties": true,
      "properties": {
        "Modules": {
          "Module1": "http://localhost:12345/",
          "Module2": "http://localhost:12346/"
        },
        "Data": {
          "Item1": "Declarations",
          "Item2": "Payments"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

My `Controller` looks like this:

```
namespace Web.Controllers
{
    public class DataController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly ILog _log;
        public Dictionary<string, string> Modules { get; set; } // << I want these to be injected!
        public Dictionary<string, string> Data { get; set; }    // <<

        public DataController(ILog log) // gets injected
        {
            _log = log;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `Modules` and `Data` be properties and not fields?

Comment: For a moment I felt dumb :-) but unfortunately even with properties the problem persists.

Comment: Does changing `Dictionary` to `IDictionary` make a difference?

Comment: No, changing doesn't make a difference...

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you plug in the container in the WebApi pipeline ?

```
config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
```

Additionally, when you want property injection, you need to use the method PropertiesAutowired()

```
builder.RegisterApiControllers(typeof(Startup).Assembly).PropertiesAutowired();
```

Comment: The Dependency Resolver is plugged in, I've updated the code. The `PropertiesAutowired` doesn't make a difference unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

The code you provide seems to be fine - I copied it and it works fine.

You must remember that properties are injected **after** the component is created, so in you controller constructor these properties are `null`, but when you hit the controller method, they are filled with proper data you provided in your json configuration file.

Comment: Do I need to make it an embedded resource...?

Comment: No, I have it as a "Content", without coping it to the output directory. I have it directly in the project directory, not in any of subdirectories